# Backbone.js - getting json data into view

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

```
User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "users",

  initialize: function(){
    this.fetch();
  }
});

  var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#container',
    template: _.template($("#home-template").html(), this.model),

    render: function() {
      $(this.el).html(this.template);
      return this;
    }
  });

  var App = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {

          '/home':       'home',
      },

      home: function() {
        var user = new User({id: 1});
        homeView = new HomeView({
          model: user
        });
        this.homeView.render();
      }
    });
```

for some reason I can't get the model data to be injects into the template for HomeView. I see the ajax request being sent off and the data coming back is correct. I put static data in the same place when calling the view and it worked fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you are executing your template at the wrong time. It should be done when `render` is called, like this:

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#container',
  template: _.template($("#home-template").html()),

  render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});
```